# Multipe Update actions does not work with conventional Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a common Update action and 2 other "update" actions. Both detach/attach a relation from/to a schoolclassCode. Without the route attributes that will not work with conventional web api routing.

How would I solve this problem without using attribute routing because then I have action names in my route like attach/detach?. I prefer nouns which describe rather a relation between resources.

```
        [HttpPut]
        [Route("attach")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Attach(DetachAttachPupilRequestDTO dto)
        {
            await service.AttachPupil(dto);
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        [Route("detach")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Detach(DetachAttachPupilRequestDTO dto)
        {
            await service.DetachPupil(dto);
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```